# Como usar ng-hide para esconder Pin no google maps?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Como faço para fazer um toggle  (hide/show) para os pins no mapa? Estou utilizando esta biblioteca [**NGMAP**](https://ngmap.github.io/):

**Meu código da view:**

```
 <div map-lazy-load="https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js"
     map-lazy-load-params="{{googleMapsUrl}}" ng-init="my_map = map">
    <ng-map class="size-map-customer" zoom="{{dataMap.zoom}}" center="{{dataMap.center}}" geo-fallback-center="{{dataMap.center}}">
     <!--//OBS: tentei usar ng-hide mas não mudou nada -->
     <marker ng-hide="filters.display_other_markers=!filters.display_other_markers" id="modal_map_{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in dataMap.collection"
                icon="{{item.image}}"
                title="{{item.name}}"
                position="{{item.lat}}, {{item.lon}}"
                z-index="{{item.index}}"
                on-click="showModal(event, item)"
        >
        </marker>
        <info-window id="cached_school">
            <div ng-non-bindable="">
                <div class="box-infowindow" ng-class="store.class">
                    <span class="selo" ng-bind-html="store.title_type"></span>
                    <h4 ng-bind-html="store.name"></h4>
                    <p ng-if="store.phone != ''">Telefone: {{store.phone}}</p>
                    <p ng-bind-html="store.address"></p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </info-window>
    </ng-map>
</div>
```